# Python 3.5: from multiprocessing import Pool ImportError: cannot import name 'Pool'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I use this example about multiprocessing in Python Documentation but I always get an error:

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
ImportError: cannot import name 'Pool'
```

I searched a lot but cannot find out the reason. Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure there is no `multiprocessing.py` file in your working directory?

Comment: Did you call your script `multiprocessing.py`? Then Python will look for `Pool` in your script, which probably isn't there.

Comment: Hello, yes, there is file multiprocessing.py in my working directory. I renamed it and the code worked. Thank you Delgan and Nander Speerstra :)

Comment: What do you mean by renamed it? What did you rename it to?